# Sort by multiple conditions ascending and descending in bash

Tags: bash

I have a following issue. I have a file containg `name,surname,age,mood`. I need to sort this file by age (descending). If age is the same that sort it my surname (ascending).
I use this: `cat $FILE |sort -r -n -t"," -k3,3 -k2,2 > "$HOME"/people.txt` But `-r` sorts both descending. How can I sort by surname ascending, please?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `sort` will perform the sort in ascending order, the `-r` flag will perform the sort in descending order; the `-r` flag can be applied to individual `-k` directives when you need to use a mix of ascending and descending, eg:

```
$ cat raw.dat
1,2,4,5
1,2,7,5
1,2,9,5
1,2,3,5
1,3,7,5
1,1,7,5
```

Sort by column #3 (descending) and then column #2 (ascending):

```
$ sort -t"," -k3nr -k2n raw.dat
1,2,9,5
1,1,7,5
1,2,7,5
1,3,7,5
1,2,4,5
1,2,3,5
```

**NOTES:**

- thanks to Ted Lyngmo for adding the `n` flag to properly handle numerics
- if data could contain a mix of characters and numerics the `n` may need to be replaced depending on desired sort method (eg, `V`)
- key takeaway is that quite a few of the `sort` flags can be applied at the  `-k`ey level

Comment: That works only for numbers 1-9. Try for example 55, 104 and 215.